# About Jasper IoT Platform

Tags: iot, esp8266

I am just bit curious. I am new in IoT and currently started working on it using ESP8266 device. I know that it needs some firmware to write and install, like smart.js.

But I have read, Jasper (http://www.jasper.com/) can connect any device and manager, monitor etc. So I am bit curious how it works internally. I am not sure whether it installs firmware created by Jasper or in other way. I was reading this article: http://www2.cumulocity.com/guides/users-guide/jasper/#link-sims

Anyone knows about this? I mean how Jasper works to connect to any devices?

Answer (score 0):

Cisco bought Jasper, which is useful for IoT business. However it might be better way for you to check Interactor([www.interactor.com](http://www.interactor.com)) which is great for IoT development. Interactor works to conntect to any device with any protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco Jasper should not be confused with device management libraries (whether they be server based, or device based or both).

Jasper is a telecom based service that allows you to see and manage the connection state of sim inserted in the device. Regardless of the state of a device, the modem and sim (provided they are powered) will connect to the telco and provide basic information about the connection.

Think of it as a network tool (server originated) for the gateway on the device, not the device itself. It allows you to force disconnect devices from the network, ban sims from the account so a stolen or runaway sim can eat through data, basic connectivity tests (is the modem powered, does the sim have permission to transmit data over the network, etc).

The main value of jasper is that it allows you to manage you data costs by applying the appropriate rate plan to each device, and disconnect devices that are using too much (for whatever reason).

Jasper does not cost anything to use, however telcos will apply a rev commit (min monthly spend) usually $500/month to gain access. the sims are the same as PCS (phone) sims, but they are on their own network internally, and are specific to that telcos jasper. i.e. you can't take 500 devices using PCS sims, and import those sims into jasper. you'd need to do a physical swap of the sims.